# Firebase Auth Limit for Admin SDK?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Does Firebase Admin SDK have the same limit as the Web?

I saw that there is a limit of **100 accounts/IP address/hour**.

But at the bottom of the page, there is a table for API limits, which is **500 requests/second**.

Slightly confused.

Reference:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits

Answer (score 3):

Those documented limits are for client SDKs.  The limits exist in order to prevent general abuse from the internet.

The Admin SDK doesn't have the same limits because it's intended to be used with privileged access from your own servers that you fully control, so there should be no abuse.  If you encounter a problem that looks like a limit, you should contact [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/) directly.

Answer (score 0):

On https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users, it is explicitly written:

> The Firebase Admin SDK provides an API for managing your Firebase Authentication users with elevated privileges. The admin user management API gives you the ability to programmatically complete the following tasks from a secure server environment:
>
> - Create new users **without any throttling or rate limiting.**